# Surface integral over a half-ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, ellipsoids

Suppose the surface $S$ is made up of the half-ellipsoid $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1, \quad z\geqslant 0,$$ together with its base in the $xy$-plane, i.e., $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2\leqslant 1$.

> **Goal:** To find $I=\int_S(y,x,z+c)\cdot\vec{\mathbf n}\,dS$, where $\vec{\mathbf n}$ is the outward pointing normal of $S$.

My idea was to split up the integral as $S_1\cup S_2$ where $S_1$ is the half-ellipsoid and $S_2$ is the base. Over $S_2$, we have $\vec{\mathbf n} = -\mathbf k$,
$$dS_2 = \frac{dx\,dy}{\vec{\mathbf n}\cdot\mathbf k}=-dx\,dy,$$
so \begin{align*}
\int_{S_2}(y,x,z+c)\cdot\vec{\mathbf n}\,dS_2&=- \iint_{S_2}(0+c)\,dx\,dy\\[4pt]
&=-c\iint_{S_2}\,dx\,dy\\[4pt] &= -\pi abc.
\end{align*}
Now I'm not sure how to proceed with the integral over $S_1$, I suspect that some kind of change of coordinates would be helpful, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I appreciate any assistance on how to proceed.

Comment: Have you learnt divergence theorem yet (also called Gauss Theorem)?

Comment: @MathLover I still need to go over that in my notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks you to find flux over closed surface, which is half ellipsoid with its base. So the easiest is to apply divergence theorem. For a closed surface and a vector field defined over the entire closed region,

$ \displaystyle \iint_S \vec F \cdot\hat{n}\,dS = \iiint_V \text{div} \vec F \, dV$

Here, $~ \vec F = (y,x,z+c)$

$\nabla \cdot \vec F = 0 + 0 + 1 = 1$

As the divergence is $1$, the flux is equal to  the volume of half ellipsoid, which is nothing but $\frac{2 \pi a b c}{3}$.

$ \displaystyle I = \iiint_V 1 \, dV = \frac{2\pi abc}{3} $